# OptimisticLockException not thrown when version has changed in spring-boot project

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Model structure:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class BaseModel<K extends Comparable> implements Serializable, Comparable<Object> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private K id;

    @Version
    private Integer version;

    // getter/setter
}

@Entity
public class MyEntity extends BaseModel<String> {
    // some fields and it's getter/setter
}
```

Record in my database for `my_entity`:

id: 1
version: 1
...

Below is my update method:

```
void update(String id, Integer currentVersion, ....) {
    MyEntity myEntity = myRepository.findOne(id);
    myEntity.setVersion(currentVersion);
    // other assignments

    myRepository.save(myEntity);
}
```

Below is the query being fired when this method is invoked.

```
update my_entity set version=?, x=?, y=?, ...
where id=? and version=?
```

I am expecting OptimisticLockException when `currentVersion` passed in above method is other than `1`.

Can any body help me why I am not getting OptimisticLockException?
I am using spring-boot for my webmvc project.

Comment: Shouldn't hibernate manage the version property?

Comment: What happens when you execute that code?

Comment: My entity is being updated successfully and version gets increased by 1 every time I execute this code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Section 11.1.54 of the JPA specification notes that:

> In general, fields or properties that are specified with the Version
>   annotation should not be updated by the application.

From experience, I can advise that some JPA providers (OpenJPA being one) actually throw an exception should you try to manually update the version field.

While not strictly an answer to your question, you can re-factor as below to ensure both portability between JPA providers and strict compliance with the JPA specification:

```
public void update(String id, Integer currentVersion) throws MyWrappedException {
    MyEntity myEntity = myRepository.findOne(id);

    if(currentVersion != myEntity.getVersion()){
        throw new MyWrappedException();
    }

    myRepository.save(myEntity);

   //still an issue here however: see below
}
```

Assuming your `update(...)` method is running in a transaction however you still have an issue with the above as section 3.4.5 of the JPA specification notes:

> 3.4.5 OptimisticLockException Provider implementations may defer writing to the database until the end of the transaction, when
>   consistent with the lock mode and flush mode settings in effect. In
>   this case, an optimistic lock check may not occur until commit time,
>   and the OptimisticLockException may be thrown in the "before
>   completion" phase of the commit. **If the OptimisticLockException must
>   be caught or handled by the application, the flush method should be
>   used by the application to force the database writes to occur. This
>   will allow the application to catch and handle optimistic lock
>   exceptions.**

Essentially then, 2 users can submit concurrent modifications for the same Entity. Both threads can pass the initial check however one will fail when the updates are flushed to the database which may be on transaction commit i.e. after your method has completed.

In order that you can catch and handle the OptimisticLock exception, your code should then look something like the below:

```
public void update(String id, Integer currentVersion) throws MyWrappedException {
    MyEntity myEntity = myRepository.findOne(id);

    if(currentVersion != myEntity.getVersion()){
        throw new MyWrappedException();
    }

    myRepository.save(myEntity);

    try{
       myRepository.flush()
    }
    catch(OptimisticLockingFailureException  ex){
       throw new MyWrappedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: As my project is spring-boot project I am using Spring JPA. And if I won't invoke `flush()` method manually, it will be automatically called at the commit time of my current transaction.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of how Spring works: your updates will be flushed on transaction commit i.e. when update() finishes execution. As the highlighted section from the JPA spec points out that does not allow you to catch/handle/rethrow - WITHIN THE BODY OF YOUR METHOD - those exceptions which may only occur at flush() . But if you're not interested in that fair enough.

Comment: It doesn't mean I am not interested but I have concern when I am using multiple repositories within a single method.

Comment: [Vlad Mihalcea](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1025118/vlad-mihalcea) also mentions possibility to use `OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT` [here](https://vladmihalcea.com/jpa-entity-version-property-hibernate/)

Answer (score 0):

Use EVICT before updating when using JPA. I did not get the @Version to work either. The property was increased but no exception was thrown when updating an object that had the wrong version-property.

The only thing I have got to work is to first EVICT the object and then save it. Then the HibernateOptimisticLockingException is thrown if the Version properties does not match.

Set the hibernates ShowSQL to 'true' to verify that the actual update sql ends with "where id=? and version=?". If the object is not evicted first, the update statement only has "where id=?", and that will (for obvious reasons) not work.

Comment: On what did you call evict?

Comment: The entities that I read and wanted optimistic locking for:

        this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().evict(obj);

Comment: Is this the right way to solve this? I've seen that the *isVersionChanged* method in Hibernates *DefaultMergeEventListener* is only called on detachedEntities. But if I map my DTO's values into my entity, the entity is of course not detached.

Comment: I don't know if this is the right way to solve it, but it's the best way we did it. The problem was that we where editing and saving an attached entity, so the version validation won't work. When we detached the entity, it works well! Actually Vlad Mihalcea in his blog about @version refers always to "detached entity".

Answer (score 0):

Optimistic hibernation lock works out of the box (You don't must put a version for Entity):

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private Long quantity;

    private Long likes;

    @Version
    private Long version;

    public Product() {
    }

  //setter and getter
//equals and hashcode
```

- repository

```java
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, Long> {}
```

- service

```java
@Service
public class ProductOptimisticLockingService {

    private final ProductRepository productRepository;

    public ProductOptimisticLockingService(ProductRepository productRepository) {
        this.productRepository = productRepository;
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public Product findById(Long id, String nameThread){

        Product product =
                productRepository
                        .findById(id)
                        .get();

        System.out.printf(
                "\n Select (%s) ....  " +
                        "(id:) %d | (likes:) %d | (quantity:) %d | (version:) %d \n",
                nameThread,
                product.getId(),
                product.getLikes(),
                product.getQuantity(),
                product.getVersion()
        );

        return product;
    }

    @Transactional(isolation = Isolation.READ_COMMITTED)
    public void updateWithOptimisticLocking(Product product, String nameThread) {

        try {
            productRepository.save(product);
        } catch (ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException ex) {
            System.out.printf(
                    "\n (%s) Another transaction is already working with a string with an ID: %d \n",
                    nameThread,
                    product.getId()
            );
        }

        System.out.printf("\n--- Update has been performed (%s)---\n", nameThread);

    }
}
```

- test

```java
@SpringBootTest
class ProductOptimisticLockingServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private ProductOptimisticLockingService productService;

    @Autowired
    private ProductRepository productRepository;

    @Test
    void saveWithOptimisticLocking() {

         /*ID may be - 1 or another. You must put the ID to pass in your methods. You must think how to write right your tests*/
        Product product = new Product();
        product.setLikes(7L);
        product.setQuantity(5L);

        productRepository.save(product);

        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

        Lock lockService = new ReentrantLock();

        Runnable taskForAlice = makeTaskForAlice(lockService);

        Runnable taskForBob = makeTaskForBob(lockService);

        executor.submit(taskForAlice);
        executor.submit(taskForBob);

        executorServiceMethod(executor);
    }

    /*------ Alice-----*/
    private Runnable makeTaskForAlice(Lock lockService){

        return  () -> {
            System.out.println("Thread-1 - Alice");

            Product product;

            lockService.lock();
            try{

                 product = productService
                        .findById(1L, "Thread-1 - Alice");
            }finally {
                lockService.unlock();
            }

            setPause(1000L); /*a pause is needed in order for the 2nd transaction to attempt
            read the line from which the 1st transaction started working*/

            lockService.lock();
            try{

                product.setQuantity(6L);
                product.setLikes(7L);

                update(product,"Thread-1 - Alice");
            }finally {
                lockService.unlock();
            }

            System.out.println("Thread-1 - Alice - end");
        };
    }

    /*------ Bob-----*/
    private Runnable makeTaskForBob(Lock lockService){

        return  () -> {

            /*the pause makes it possible to start the transaction first
            from Alice*/
            setPause(50L);
            System.out.println("Thread-2 - Bob");

            Product product;

            lockService.lock();
            try{
                product = findProduct("Thread-2 - Bob");
            }finally {
                lockService.unlock();
            }

            setPause(3000L); /*a pause is needed in order for the 1st transaction to update
             the string that the 2nd transaction is trying to work with*/

            lockService.lock();
            try{
                product.setQuantity(5L);
                product.setLikes(10L);

                update(product,"Thread-2 - Bob");
            }finally {
                lockService.unlock();
            }

            System.out.println("Thread-2 - Bob - end");
        };
    }

    private void update(Product product, String nameThread){
        productService
                .updateWithOptimisticLocking(product, nameThread);
    }

    private Product findProduct(String nameThread){

        return productService
                .findById(1L, nameThread);
    }

    private void setPause(long timeOut){
        try {
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(timeOut);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

       private void executorServiceMethod(ExecutorService executor){

        try {
            executor.awaitTermination(10L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        executor.shutdown();
    }
}
```