# @Version - Spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-rest

I've been trying to get `@Version` to work but I can't seem to do it, I'm building a **Rest API**, when I try to edit I want to make sure that the version that the user is editing is the current one and not one that was opened and edited by other person, for that I used ***`@javax.persistence.Version`***,

This is currently my controller code:

```
@InitBinder("song")
protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.setValidator(new SongValidator());
}

@PutMapping("{song}")
public ResponseEntity<?> update(@PathVariable("song") int songId, @Valid @RequestBody Song song) {
    Song currentSong = songService.findSongByIdAndDeletedAtIsNull(songId);
    if (currentSong == null) {
        return new ResponseEntity(new CustomErrorType(
                "Song with id " + songId + " not found."
        ), HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }

    currentSong.setName(song.getName());
    currentSong.setLyrics(song.getLyrics());
    currentSong.setTypes(song.getTypes());

    songService.save(currentSong);
    return new ResponseEntity<Song>(currentSong, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

On the model I have this:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;

private String name;

private String slug;

@Lob
private String lyrics;

@CreationTimestamp
private Date createdAt;

private Date updatedAt = new Date();

private Date deletedAt;

@OrderBy("id")
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "song_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "types_id",  referencedColumnName = "id"))
private List<SongType> types;

@JsonProperty(access = Access.READ_ONLY)
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "name")
@JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId=true)
@ManyToOne
private User user;

@javax.persistence.Version
private int version;

public int getVersion() {
    return version;
}

public void setVersion(int version) {
    this.version = version;
}
... other getters and setters ...
```

This was the json I used to update the song:

```
{
    "id": 24
    "name": "New song for Update test",
    "slug": "new-song-for-update-test",
    "lyrics": "lyrics for the song update",
    "types": [
        {
            "id": 2
        }
    ],
    "version": 30
}
```

I used the `.properties` file to show the `sql` binding and the version that the update is doing is not the one sent in the `json`, instead of being

```
where id=24 and version=30, is where id=24 and version=31
```

Comment: You pass the version in the JSON but don't do anything with it. You either need to set it on the entity to be updated or do you own manual check. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30098350/optimisticlockexception-not-thrown-when-version-has-changed-in-spring-boot-proje/30101542#30101542

Comment: I already tried to `currentSong.setVersion(song.getVersion())` but it still didn't do anything, I already made a manual check for testing purposes, but I though that jpa would do it automatically.

Comment: What I've found with this is that if you are using Spring Boot Devtools, make a modification somewhere and allow the application to automatically restart, OptimisticLockException will begin to be thrown whenever there is a violation. I cannot understand why it would start working in that manner.

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar situation on our project, and what we found was that the @Version validation only works over detatch objects. At least using Hibernate, like our case.

And vlad mihalcea in his blog actually refers always to "detached entity" [here](https://vladmihalcea.com/jpa-entity-version-property-hibernate/)

Your *currentSong* entity that is get from database is attached to the context.

I suggest you to clone or map your *currenSong* to a copy, and save this detached copy.
Or detach it from the context before saving. (we have done this last one).

Using like:

```
entityManager.detach(entityObject)
```